# Says misaligned &. Not sure why

Tags: ampersand

```
\[
P\{\text{ever enter}\ j\rvert \text{start in}\ i\}
= P\bigg\{\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \{X_n = j \bigg\rvert X_0 = i \bigg\}
& \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P\{X_n = j \rvert X_0 = i\}
& = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_{ij}^{n}
& = 0
\]
```

Comment: `\[` is for a single displayed equation it does not accept `&` as it is single line it would be meaningless, you need to delete the `&` or use `align` or similar environment,

Answer (score 2):

I assume there are missing new line commands as well as an inside `aligned` or similar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{aligned}
    P\{\text{ever enter}\ j\rvert \text{start in}\ i\}
    & = P\bigg\{\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \{X_n = j \bigg\rvert X_0 = i \bigg\}
    \\
    & \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P\{X_n = j \rvert X_0 = i\}
    \\
    & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_{ij}^{n}
    \\
    & = 0
  \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The inner `aligned` makes sense, if the whole system gets one equation
number; e.g., if environment `gather` or `equation` replaces `\[` and `\]`.

Without numbers, the star form `align*` can be used instead of `\[`/`\]` and the inner `aligned`.

Comment: Thank you. I was unsure of the set up for aligned equations for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

While Heiko's answer addresses the main point, it doesn't fix several typographic mistakes in the source.

1. `\rvert` is a **r**ight **vert**ical bar, used as a delimiter on the right; it should be `\mid` when used as a separator for conditions and `|` if it follows `\left`, `\right` or `\[bB]ig[g]m` (see below)
2. `\bigg` makes an ordinary symbol; in order to produce a delimiter, it should be `\biggl` or `\biggr`, depending on the side; for a separator (technically a relation symbol) it should be `\biggm`; such `lrm` variants exist for `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` and `\Bigg`.
3. `\text{ever enter }j` and `\text{ever enter}\ j` are clumsy and error prone; much better is `\text{ever enter $j$}`
4. When a big delimiter is followed by a `\sum`-like operator (here `\bigcup`) having a wide condition underneath, it's better to give some more room with `\,`
5. A brace is missing in the first summation.

Complete example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
  P\{\text{ever enter $j$} \mid \text{start in $i$}\}
  & = P\biggl\{\,\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \{X_n = j\} \biggm| X_0 = i \biggr\}
  \\
  & \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P\{X_n = j \mid X_0 = i\}
  \\
  & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_{ij}^{n}
  \\
  & = 0
  \end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]